# Splitting text in tab delimited format in python, adding it to list and writing it to a file... is there a better way?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm new to scripting in python. I am extracting data from a tab delimited `vcf` file. My script works, but I have tried to concatenate the strings into a list using `word[0:2]` but this doesn`t work, so instead I add the data by splitting it manually:

i.e: `word[0] + "\t" + word[1] + "\t" + word[2]`

I am not sure why I have to do this as when I use `lst = word[0:2]` the command returns "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list. Why is this?

My entire code is:

```
lst = []
for line in my_file:
    if 'chr' in line:   
        word = line.split("\t")
        adp = word[7].split(";")
        pc = word[9].split(":")
        s = adp[0].split("=")
        lst = word[0] + "\t" + word[1] + "\t" + word[3] + "\t" + word[4] + "\t" + s[1] + "\t" + pc[6] + "\n"
        outputfile.write(lst)
```

How can I make this more concise?

Thanks

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVCF is a python module to parse variant call format files --- I don't know if this is what you want or if you're better with your DIBY approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) when concatenating strings:

```
lst = []
for line in my_file:
    if 'chr' in line:   
        word = line.split("\t")
        lst.extend(word[7].split(";"))
        lst.extend(word[9].split(":"))
        lst.extend(adp[0].split("="))
        out = '\t'.join(lst)
        outputfile.write(out)
```